# image list, listview,picturebox

Tags: c#

I wanted to show my pics in picturebox. but also wanted to show a preview of pics.
When user select a pic, it is shown in picbox but i have problem in resoulution.

Here is my code

```
  private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           

            ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Title = "Open an Image File";
            ofd.FileName = "";
            ofd.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp";
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
 DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\pic");  
foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles()) 
{
this.imageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(file.FullName));
}
this.listView1.View = View.LargeIcon;
this.imageList1.ImageSize = new Size(40, 40);
this.listView1.LargeImageList = this.imageList1;

 for (int j=0; j < this.imageList1.Images.Count; j++)                           {
  ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
                                item.ImageIndex = j;                                
                                listView1.Items.Add(item);

                                ListViewItem item2 = new ListViewItem();
                                item2.SubItems.Add(j.ToString());                     



                            }  
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int i = this.listView1.FocusedItem.Index;

            this.PicBox1.Image = this.imageList1.Images[i];

        }
```

On click i see only image of resolution of (40,40) becuse i have set it
this.imageList1.ImageSize = new Size(40, 40); and not orignal size.
How can I have it.
2-
I want to write also image names and index(image no) under each images.
Its it possible.
reagrsd,

Answer (score 2):

I suppose, that after you have loaded an image to the imageList with resolution 40, 40, there is no way to make it higher.

Answer (score 1):

You should save the original picture in another container like `List<>` and display the original image from the list and not from the imagelist :)

Answer (score 0):

```
   -Create a new imagelist (imagelist1)**
   -Add images to your imagelist 
   -Create a new listview (listview1)
   -Create a picturebox (picturebox1)
   -Create a new button (button1)
   -Create another button (button2)**

    -Import  images from imagelist1 to listview1

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Scrollable = true;
        listView1.View = View.LargeIcon;
        imageList1.ImageSize = new Size(100, 100);
        listView1.LargeImageList = imagelist1;

        for (int i = 0; i < imagelist1.Images.Count; ++i)
        {
            string s = imagelist1.Images.Keys[i].ToString();
            ListViewItem lstItem = new ListViewItem();
            lstItem.ImageIndex = i;
            lstItem.Text = s;
            listView1.Items.Add(lstItem);
        }
    }

     - Set the selected image into your picture box from listview

      private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this != null && listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            ListViewItem lvi = listView1.SelectedItems[0];
            string imagekeyname = lvi.Text;

            if (this.pictureBox1.Image != null)
            {
                this.pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
                this.pictureBox1.Image = null;
            }

            //set the selected image into your picturebox
            this.pictureBox1.Image = imagelist1.Images[imagekeyname];

        }
    }
```

and its done.